# Multiple file uploads using XMLHttpRequest() fails in IE11 and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, api

I have fritten following  tool to upload multiple files to a api service and it works fine in chrome and firefox, but it gives me a bad request error in IE11 and edge, I believe, the ccode doesn't pass the files with required parameter

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


</head>
<body>


<label for="queuemanagername">QUEUE MANAGER NAME:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="queuemanagername" name="queuemanagername" value=""><br>

  <label for="queuename">queue name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="queuename" name="queuename" value=""><br>
    <input type="file"  id="inpFile" multiple><br>
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label><br>
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
 <button id="btnUpload"> Upload files</button>

    <script>
       
    const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
    const btnUpload = document.getElementById("btnUpload");
    
    btnUpload.addEventListener("click",function () {
         //var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var formData = new FormData();
         xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/uploadFile", true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
        
         
    for (const file of inpFile.files) {
    formData.append("multipleFiles",file);
    
    }
         
         
         xhr.send(formData);
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be easier, if you'd actually have the form. In `form`'s submit handler you could do `var formData = new FormData(this.form);`, and all the files would be assigned to the data.

Comment: Actually the code only worked in firefox and chrome with "const file of inpFile.files"

Comment: I didn't express any doubts it wouldn't had worked, the suggested code will work in Chrome and FF too.